# Send Information of javascript to google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, phonegap-build, google-sheets-api

I want the data I have in the `id` tag `deviceProperties` to be sent to a Google Sheet:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' +
            'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to read about Google Sheet API and make a request to it. Just that https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can easily fulfill your request making a [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) call with the method [`spreadsheets.values.append`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append). You can check out some examples [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append#examples_1). That way you can add the tag elements at the end of your table, with each field represented by a column. Please, don't hesitate to write back to me if you still have any questions.

Comment: Atchually I created an app using css/html/javascript. So i want to send details of android version etc( Information I have in id tag)  when a new user launches the app to a google sheet that i created.